# Can I trace raw HTTP requests used in gradle for getting dependencies?

Tags: debugging, gradle, apache-httpclient-4.x

Is there any way to trace the raw HTTP requests made by Gradle for getting dependencies for debugging purpose as I'm not able to make it work with proxy using Kerberos.

I tried setting Apache HTTP logging setting as per https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html

But, nothings coming up in Gradle debug.

Can I get some pointers on this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `gradle build` displays dependencies urls

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.5'
```

will give the first time the dependency is downloaded

```
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-csv/1.5/commons-csv-1.5.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-csv/1.5/commons-csv-1.5.jar
```

Comment: Actually it is coming can't get the resource. But I feel my proxy settings are correct and I'm able to open the same in browser. I want to see raw HTTP request and the responce code. So I can find where lies the issue.